# Why is there a `united-kingdom` tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

Why does the [united-kingdom](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) tag exist?

I would think that makes any question tagged with it "too localised"…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree.

As mentioned questions are not supposed to be geographically localized unless there is a compelling reason for the localization (e.g. if you were researching an art style from a particular province or location).

If that compelling reason doesn't exist then the tag shouldn't either because it just leads to people using it incorrectly at a later date. I'm not convinced that asking for a statistical answer and then limiting it to the UK is a good enough reason to introduce the tag.

Having said that, tags can be edited as per normal. There is no reason for the [united-states](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag on [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/72/70). Tags will naturally disappear from the list once nothing is referencing them.

Comment: @Sardathrion Burnination isn't required - it was only on two questions :)

Comment: The tag appears to have been removed from the questions so should die on its own.

Comment: @Sardathrion Yep, it's been culled from the list (it can take up to 24 hours, the script must run just once per day).

Answer (score -1):

The UK is geographically a small country but it has a large population.  64.1 million people.  The USA (for which there is also a tag) has more but only about 5 times more.  A UK question may only reach 1/5th of the people a USA question does, but this is still potentially a lot of people.

Comment: I think the fundamental question is, "Would someone asking a question, or looking to answer a question, find it useful to view this tag?"