# Why is a question about the UK get closed yet a question about Japan not get closed?

Tags: discussion

[Question about etiquette in Japan](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/is-shaking-hands-after-a-judo-competition-bad-etiquette-in-japan)

Can someone tell me why this is not considered too localised?  It's only relevant to one country.  Yet if I post anything about the UK (another small island nation) it gets closed.

Comment: "Too Localised" has not been a close reason for quite some time.

Answer (score 4):

The question is about how the etiquette transfers across countries. Judo started in Japan where bowing is normal, and it has moved into parts of the world where handshakes are normal. The question is basically about what happens when these two cultures mix.

I am not sure what you are referring to with the UK. I do not see any closed questions for you that are about the UK.

Comment: Not closed, but there is https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7123/are-injuries-from-assault-more-severe-than-those-sustained-during-martial-arts-p

Comment: @SeanDuggan We previously discussed why that question and a similar one were ill-received: https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/5961